# zfs shows in pool but not in datasets

Tags: zfs, proxmox

I transferred my freenas zfs pool to proxmox integrated zfs (linux basically) and when I ls the **pool** it shows the folders I used to have but when i do `zfs list` it doesn't show up. Could I just `rm folder` these files or will it cause problems on zfs?

I think the problem with these folders is that they're space separated (freenas let me do it so i did it).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely rmdir the unused mountpoint directories if there is nothing mounted on them.

Comment: ok I blindly trusted you xD but all seems good. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. :-)